# Correct way to handle readFile and writeFile exceptions

Tags: haskell, file-io, error-handling

I'm writing an application in Haskell and would like to display a meaningful error message to the user if `readFile` or `writeFile` fails. I'm currently catching `IOError`s with `Control.Exception.tryJust` and converting them to human-readable text.

However, I'm having trouble figuring out which errors I should catch and how to extract information from them. For example, assuming "/bin" is a directory and "/bin/ls" is a file, `readFile "/bin"` and `readFile "/bin/ls/asdf"` both give "inappropriate type" but (in my opinion) they are different errors. In the case of the first one, I could recover by processing each file within the directory, whereas the second is more like a "does not exist" type of error.

In relation to the previous example, there doesn't seem to be a portable way of catching "inappropriate type" errors. Looking at [GHC.IO.Exception](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.Exception.html#IOErrorType), `InappropriateType` is marked GHC-only so I can't just pattern match on `ioeGetErrorType`. I could pattern match on `ioeGetErrorString` but I'm not sure if those strings are always the same across different platforms, compilers, locales, etc.

In summary, my questions are:

1. Which exceptions should I be catching for `readFile`/`writeFile`?
2. Once I have an exception, how should I go about extracting information from it?
3. Is there a portable way of catching the GHC-only exceptions such as `InappropriateType`?

**Update:**

Based on @ErikR's answer I'm looking at the fields of `GHC.IO.Exception.IOException` with the following Haskell program:

```
import Control.Exception (try)
import GHC.IO.Exception (IOException(..))
import qualified Data.ByteString as B


main :: IO ()
main = do
    try (readFile "/nonexistent") >>= printException
    try (writeFile "/dev/full" " ") >>= printException
    try (readFile "/root") >>= printException
    try (readFile "/bin") >>= printException
    try (writeFile "/bin" "") >>= printException
    try (readFile "/bin/ls/asdf") >>= printException
    try (writeFile "/bin/ls/asdf" "") >>= printException
    try (B.readFile "/dev/null") >>= printException

    -- I have /media/backups mounted as read-only. Substitute your own read-only
    -- filesystem for this one
    try (writeFile "/media/backups/asdf" "") >>= printException

printException :: Either IOError a -> IO ()
printException (Right _) = putStrLn "No exception caught"
printException (Left e) = putStrLn $ concat [ "ioe_filename = "
                                            , show $ ioe_filename e
                                            , ", ioe_description = "
                                            , show $ ioe_description e
                                            , ", ioe_errno = "
                                            , show $ ioe_errno e
                                            ]
```

The output on Debian Sid GNU/Linux with GHC 7.10.3 is:

```
ioe_filename = Just "/nonexistent", ioe_description = "No such file or directory", ioe_errno = Just 2
ioe_filename = Just "/dev/full", ioe_description = "No space left on device", ioe_errno = Just 28
ioe_filename = Just "/root", ioe_description = "Permission denied", ioe_errno = Just 13
ioe_filename = Just "/bin", ioe_description = "is a directory", ioe_errno = Nothing
ioe_filename = Just "/bin", ioe_description = "Is a directory", ioe_errno = Just 21
ioe_filename = Just "/bin/ls/asdf", ioe_description = "Not a directory", ioe_errno = Just 20
ioe_filename = Just "/bin/ls/asdf", ioe_description = "Not a directory", ioe_errno = Just 20
ioe_filename = Just "/dev/null", ioe_description = "not a regular file", ioe_errno = Nothing
ioe_filename = Just "/media/backups/asdf", ioe_description = "Read-only file system", ioe_errno = Just 30
```

Comment: I'm not optimistic about "portable" exceptions with the current state of the Haskell infrastructure. We've been stuck in one-compiler mode for a number of years. Here's hoping that changes soon.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> 1. Which exceptions should I be catching for readFile/writeFile?

Under OS X, if you use `openFile` followed by `hGetContents` instead of `readFile` then you will get different exceptions for the cases you mention.

`openFile "/bin/ls/asdf" ...` will throw a "no such file or directory" exception whereas `openFile "/bin" ...` will throw "inappropriate type".

Under Linux both open calls will throw a "inappropriate type" exception. However, you can distinguish between the two via the `ioe_errno` and `ioe_description` fields:

```
import System.IO
import GHC.IO.Exception
import Control.Exception

foo path = do
  h <- openFile path ReadMode
  hClose h

show_ioe :: IOException -> IO ()
show_ioe e = do
  putStrLn $ "errno: " ++ show (ioe_errno e)
  putStrLn $ "description: " ++ ioe_description e

bar path = foo path `catch` show_ioe
```

Sample ghci session:

```
*Main> bar "/bin"
errno: Nothing
description: is a directory
*Main> bar "/bin/ls/asd"
errno: Just 20
description: Not a directory
```

> 2. Once I have an exception, how should I go about extracting information from it?

Each exception has its own structure. The definition of an IOException may be found [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.IO.Exception.html#IOException).

To bring the field accessors into scope you need to import `GHC.IO.Exception`.

> 3. Is there a portable way of catching the GHC-only exceptions such as InappropriateType?

As @dfeuer said, for all practical purposes GHC is the only Haskell implementation at this time.

**Update**

Results from running your program. I didn't include the last result because I didn't have a read-only filesystem around to test it on, but I'm sure the error would be the same.

```
ioe_filename = Just "/nonexistent", ioe_description = "No such file or directory", ioe_errno = Just 2
ioe_filename = Just "/dev/full", ioe_description = "Permission denied", ioe_errno = Just 13
ioe_filename = Just "/root", ioe_description = "is a directory", ioe_errno = Nothing
ioe_filename = Just "/bin", ioe_description = "is a directory", ioe_errno = Nothing
ioe_filename = Just "/bin", ioe_description = "Is a directory", ioe_errno = Just 21
ioe_filename = Just "/bin/ls/asdf", ioe_description = "Not a directory", ioe_errno = Just 20
ioe_filename = Just "/bin/ls/asdf", ioe_description = "Not a directory", ioe_errno = Just 20
ioe_filename = Just "/dev/null", ioe_description = "not a regular file", ioe_errno = Nothing
```

Comment: I still get "inappropriate type" from both using System.IO.openFile on GHC 7.10.3 for GNU/Linux.

Comment: I guess the exact exception is OS dependent then - I tested it under OS X + GHC 7.10.2. Updated answer.

Comment: However - you do get a slightly different message - "not a directory" vs. "is a directory" - so that is a way to distinguish between the two.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me towards ioe_description, that ended up being exactly what I needed. I've updated my question with the strings that I'm catching on GNU/Linux but I don't have access to OS X. Could you please check that they're the same on OS X. Thanks again for the help!

Comment: Actually I would base it on `ioe_errno` because on Unix/Linux/OS X systems the description string is a function of the errno error code and the errno codes are much more likely to be the same. If you give me a program that generates the errors I'll run it on my OS X system.

Comment: I added a Haskell program to my question. You might need to change some of the paths since I'm not sure what OS X has under /dev/ and whether or not /root exists.